# display multiple table as query result using ORDER BY in PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I need a help on these, where I want to display the query result with multiple table as the assets have different attributes, it will be ORDER BY category. Let's say, Category = Laptop will list all the laptop details, TV will have its own table with its features & so on. All of this will be on the same page but breakdown by tables. How can I achieve this? Here's the part where I suppose the problem lies. Any help is highly appreciated!

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$assetid = $row['assetid'];
$name = $row['name'];
$category = $row['category'];
$manufacturer = $row['manufacturer'];
$type = $row['type'];
$size = $row['size'];
$price = $row['price'];
$warranty = $row['warranty'];
$description = $row['description'];

if ($category == "1 - LAPTOP")
{
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Asset ID</th>
<th>Category</th>
<th>Name | Model</th>
<th>Manufacturer</th>
<th>Type</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Warranty</th>
<th>Description</th>
</tr>";

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $assetid . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $category . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $name. "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $manufacturer. "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $type. "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $price . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $warranty . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $description . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
}

elseif ($category == "2 - TV")
{
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Asset ID</th>
<th>Category</th>
<th>Name | Model</th>
<th>Manufacturer</th>
<th>Type</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Warranty</th>
<th>Description</th>
</tr>";

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $assetid . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $category . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $name. "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $manufacturer. "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $type. "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $price . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $warranty. "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $description . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
}

elseif ($subassetcategory == "3 - DESK")
{
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Asset ID</th>
<th>Category</th>
<th>Name | Model</th>
<th>Manufacturer</th>
<th>Type</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Description</th>
</tr>";

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $assetid . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $category . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $name. "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $manufacturer. "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $type. "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $price . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $description . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
}

elseif ($subassetcategory == "4 - TELEPHONE")
{
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Asset ID</th>
<th>Category</th>
<th>Name | Model</th>
<th>Manufacturer</th>
<th>Type</th>
<th>Description</th>
</tr>";

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $assetid . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $category . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $name. "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $manufacturer. "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $type. "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $description . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
}

}
}

else
{ 
echo "<br> No record found </br>";
}
```

Comment: Could you explain the problem itself a little bit more

Comment: @Mythje I just want it to display by its Category. As you know, like a report, it will display all the fields & some of the asset didn't have some fields. Therefore, I want it to display several tables where Laptop, TV, Desk, Telephone have their own table. Do you understand me? Sorry, I'm not very good in explaining.

edit: and as you can see, the above code returns the result fine, Ordered By and all, just the table is not presentable. Every row got its own table header. I want for Laptop, only 1 header for every rows, and so for the TV, Desk & Telephone.

Comment: Then you should get the <th> tags out of the while loop so that it only displays once right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big problem I see in your code is its repetition, it completely breaks the [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). Also, you have your categories hard coded in your code, and stored in your DB. I modified the script, so that it should create now a generic table header whenever a new category is found in the resultset.

Please try this (instead of all your code) and see if it works for you:

```
$categ = '';
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$assetid = $row['assetid'];
$name = $row['name'];
$category = $row['category'];
$manufacturer = $row['manufacturer'];
$type = $row['type'];
$size = $row['size'];
$price = $row['price'];
$warranty = $row['warranty'];
$description = $row['description'];

if ($category != $categ)
{
$categ = $category;
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Asset ID</th>
<th>Category</th>
<th>Name | Model</th>
<th>Manufacturer</th>
<th>Type</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Warranty</th>
<th>Description</th>
</tr>";
}

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $assetid . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $category . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $name. "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $manufacturer. "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $type. "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $price . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $warranty . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $description . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";

} //while
} //if
```

This code assumes that your results are comming with `ORDER BY category`

Comment: Thanks for your code. It's much better than what I've got previously but I need a little bit more. Is there a way where I can hide all the empty fields for every table? Like for example, if Telephone doesn't have warranty, so I don't want the warranty field to be there looks empty, better hide it right? But really thanks for this code. It's really almost what I want.

Comment: You can show your appreciation with an upvote and an accept. Regarding your second question - it would be not quite straight forward to see if all the records for a category are missing some values - you can however iterate over the whole resultset, memorize which columns to display for each category, then in this code put `if`s around all columns

Comment: that's exactly what I want to know. As of now, I managed to get the desired output but it only returns 1 row for each category & I'm doing it by AGAIN go against the DRY principle because that's the only thing I could think of for this. Therefore, I would really glad to know, how do I put the "if" statement around the columns? I've tried so many ways but still couldn't figure it out. Could you point out to me by showing an example?

Comment: Create another question for it.

Comment: I'm sorry but do you mean to post another question on SO?

Answer (score 0):

What about doing it like this? :

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
     if ($category == "1 - LAPTOP")
     {
         echo "<table border='1'>
         <tr>
         <th>Asset ID</th>
         <th>Category</th>
         <th>Name | Model</th>
         <th>Manufacturer</th>
         <th>Type</th>
         <th>Price</th>
         <th>Warranty</th>
         <th>Description</th>
         </tr>";
    }

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $assetid = $row['assetid'];
        $name = $row['name'];
        $category = $row['category'];
        $manufacturer = $row['manufacturer'];
        $type = $row['type'];
        $size = $row['size'];
        $price = $row['price'];
        $warranty = $row['warranty'];
        $description = $row['description'];

        if ($category == "1 - LAPTOP")
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $assetid . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $category . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $name. "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $manufacturer. "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $type. "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $price . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $warranty . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $description . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "</table>";
         }
     }
}

else
{ 
echo "<br> No record found </br>";
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the code but I'm in a hurry now. I'll try this once I get home & I'll get back to you once I did. Really appreciate this!

Comment: do you mean I have to do that for all the category? Doesn't it seems like the one I did before? I've tried it but it's almost the same as mine. Or did I understood wrongly?

Comment: This is just an expample of the Laptop category. I just took the header part outside the while so it only displays it once.

Comment: yup I've tried to expand it & tried so many ways but it only returns 1 row. Do you know why is that?